# rewrite php to png with some pramaters on .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, png, url-rewriting

I want rewrite my link

```
/svlist/sv_image.php?ip=109.73.77.38&port=35115&game=cs2d
```

to

```
/svlist/cs2d/109.73.77.38:35115.png
```

I'm really new on that stuff.

```
RewriteRule ^(svlist)/([^.]*)\/([0-9]+):([^.]*)\.png$ $1/sv_image.php?ip=$3&port=$4&game=$2 [L,NC]
```

I tried this one and failed..

Comment: You forgot to include `.` as a valid char in your IP-matching logic. e.g. should be `[0-9.]`+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^svlist/([^/]+)/([0-9.]+):([0-9]+)\.png$ /svlist/sv_image?ip=$2&port=$3&game=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite */svlist/$var1/$var2:$var3.png* into */svlist/sv_image.php?ip=$var2&port=$var3&game=$var1* you could check this:

```
# once per .htaccess file
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^svlist/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9\.]*):([0-9]*).png /svlist/sv_image.php?ip=$2&port=$3&game=$1 [L,NC]
```

But if the URLs that you want to rewrite are */svlist/sv_image.php?ip=$var1&port=$var2&game=$var3* into */svlist/$var3/$var1:$var2.png* then try to check these rewrite condition and rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ip=([0-9\.]*)&port=([0-9]*)&game=([a-z0-9-_]+)
RewriteRule ^svlist/sv_image.php /svlist/%3/%1:%2.png [L,NC]
```